# HTTPS での POST 送信時、稀に応答なしで処理がフリーズしてしまう

Tags: spresense, arduino

HTTPS POST送信した際、ごく稀に応答がなく、そのまま処理がフリーズしてしまいます。
タイムアウト等フリーズを回避する方法はありますでしょうか？
＜開発環境等＞
・spresense本体＋spresense lte拡張ボード
・Arduino IDE

下記コードの `client.post(postPath, contentType, postData);` 個所でごく稀に応答なしになります。

```
void send_notify(String message) {

  // LTE接続開始
  while (true) {
    if (lteAccess.begin() == LTE_SEARCHING) {
      if (lteAccess.attach(lte_apn, lte_user_name, lte_password) == LTE_READY) {
        print_wrap(1,"lte attach succeeded",0);
        break;
      }
      print_wrap(1,"lte An error occurred, shutdown and try again.",0);
      lteAccess.shutdown();
      sleep(1);
    }
  }

  // 送信データ準備
  String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nAuthorization: Bearer " + String(notify_token);
  String postData = "message=" + String(message);

  // HTTPS POST送信
  client.post(postPath, contentType, postData);

  // 応答コードを表示
  int statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();
  String response = client.responseBody();

  sleep(1);

  // LTE接続停止
  print_wrap(1,"lte disconnecting",0);

  client.stop();
  lteAccess.shutdown();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

別の場所でも書きましたが、フリーズを回避する方法として、Watchdogというライブラリが使えると思います。
[SPRESENSE Watchdogライブラリ](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_watchdog_%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA)

このライブラリを使うことで `send_notify()` 関数が30秒以上返らなかった場合、強制的にリセットすることができます。

```
// Watchdogを初期化
Watchdog.begin();
// Watchdogタイマーを15000msecで開始
Watchdog.start(30000);

send_notify("hogehoge");

// Watchdogタイマーを終了
Watchdog.stop();
// Watchdogをファイナライズ
Watchdog.end();
```

ご参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。とりあえずフリーズすることはなくなりそうです。根本的にはまだまだ不具合ありそうですがまだ新しい物なので仕方がないです

Comment: 最近ファームウェアのアップデートがあったようで、これを使ったらフリーズ問題が解決するかもしれません。私もこのアップデートでフリーズ問題がだいぶ減りました。[SDK Ver2.3.0 Example lte_awsiotを長時間実行したら、エラーとリセットが発生する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/82861/sdk-ver2-3-0-example-lte-awsiot%e3%82%92%e9%95%b7%e6%99%82%e9%96%93%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%a8%e3%83%aa%e3%82%bb%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%81%8c%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)