# SDK Ver2.3.0 Example lte_awsiotを長時間実行したら、エラーとリセットが発生する

Tags: spresense

[動作手順]
[lte_aws_iot_サンプルアプリケーション](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_lte_aws_iot_%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)
**log1**

```
【ログ１　6時間ぐらい】
sdkTest/sub hello from SDK QOS0 : 22592
Subscribe callback
sdkTest/sub hello from SDK QOS1 : 22593
Subscribe callback
sdkTest/sub hello from SDK QOS0 : 22594
Failed to deactivate PDN :-115
```

**log2**

```
【ログ２　1時間ぐらい】
sdkTest/sub hello from SDK QOS0 : 4682
Subscribe callback
sdkTest/sub hello from SDK QOS1 : 4683
Auto Reconnect is enabled, Reconnecting attempt will start now
app_restart_cb called. reason:Modem restart by self.
```

Comment: spresense sdk 最新V2.3.1で48Hエージングテストを実施してエラーが発生しませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

ご指摘のModemリセットが発生する件に関しまして、Spresense LTE拡張ボードのファームウェアアップデートを用意致しました。
こちらのファームウェアをご利用頂くと、ご指摘のリセット問題が改善されると思われます。
お手数をおかけしますが、下記リンクをご参照になり、是非ファームウェアアップデートの実施をご検討ください。

[更新内容](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/downloads/lte_downloads/lte_updatenote/)
[ファームウェアアップデートツール](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/downloads/lte_downloads/lte_fwuptool/)

今後ともSPRESENSEをよろしくお願いいたします。