# spresenseのLTE通信エラー時の対応について

Tags: spresense

spresenseのLTEボードを用いて通信をしていると、
時々、

```
ERROR:LTEClient:137 connect() error : 113
```

のエラーが発生し、プログラムが停止してします。
当エラーへの対応はどうしたらよいのかご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

`ECONNABORTED` は `"Software caused connection abort"` なのでIPスタックから接続を中断されているようです。
なので、 `lteAccess.getStatus();` を使って状態を確認し、　`LTE_ERROR` ならもう一度 `lteAccess.attach` を実施するとよいと思います。

また、古いファームウェアだとModemリセットが発生するようなので、同様のエラーが出てくるのかなと思います。
以下のページを参照してファームウェアアップデートを行ってみるといかがでしょうか？
[Updateツール（RK_02_01_01_10_41_15  -> RK_02_01_02_10_108_54）](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/downloads/lte_downloads/lte_fwuptool/)

参考
[SDK Ver2.3.0 Example lte_awsiotを長時間実行したら、エラーとリセットが発生する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/82861/sdk-ver2-3-0-example-lte-awsiot%e3%82%92%e9%95%b7%e6%99%82%e9%96%93%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%a8%e3%83%aa%e3%82%bb%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%81%8c%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)